# Compile failure only when I run it as a remote service using PsExec

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2012, psexec, pdb-files

I am trying to run compile tests on a series of build machines so I've written a script to distribute the jobs to each machine. I am using PsExec from microsoft which installs a service on the build machines where it runs commands from. On each build machine I have a batch file which calls a python script that runs all of the tests on want. The original script will pass what test to run, as well as logging information so I can store the results and keep track of it later.

The original script can call all of the machines and execute the batch file properly. If I run the batch file locally on each machine it calls the python script correctly which compiles everything fine. But when I run the batch file remotely from the original script I get the following compile error

```
fatal error C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation
```

over and over again. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 12 on each machine and python 2.7. Does anyone know why that error would happen only because the script calling the bat file that calls the python script? Any help or push in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Can you post an example of what parameters you are passing to PsExec? That might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered such error on VS2010 except I'm using Cygwin's ssh.

The problem that instead of dealing with debug information on his own, `cl.exe` compiler runs `mspdbsrv.exe` as a central server. When you run compiler from the interactive session, everything works fine, but when `cl.exe` is run from remote session of some kind, it fails to connect to actual `mspdbsrv.exe` and eventually fails with C1902 error.

It seems that despite the fact Cygwin ssh runs `bash` (shell) from `.\Administrator`, somewhere inside RPC API, account from which service runs is used (`.\cyg_server` in my case). Here are the screenshot from API Monitor tracing `cl.exe`:

[image]

I've managed to solve that problem by changing sshd service user to `.\Administrator`. You can probably do the trick with PsExec.

Comment: @EditedContent, if you solved this using [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), please post the required command line options (e.g. `-u Administrator`, `-i`, `-h`, etc) for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the relevant part of MSDN

[Fatal Error C1902](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7hea02.aspx)

> "...For example, you might have copied the files so you could invoke
>   the compiler or link tool from the command prompt without setting the
>   PATH environment variable accordingly."

**So ensure that the PATH environment variable is same for both the cases local and remote**.

Answer (score 0):

> fatal error C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation

From MSDN and [Expand Fatal Error C1902](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8y7hea02.aspx):

> A program database file (.pdb) was created using a newer version of
>   mspdbXX.dll than the one the compiler found on your system. This error
>   usually indicates that mspdbsrv.exe or mspdbcore.dll are missing or
>   have different versions than mspdbXX.dll. (The XX placeholder in the
>   mspdbXX.dll file name changes with each product release. For example,
>   in Visual Studio 2005 the file name is mspdb80.dll.)
>        Ensure matching versions of mspdbsrv.exe, mspdbcore.dll, and mspdbXX.dll are installed on your system. Ensure that mismatched
>   versions have not been copied to the directory that contains the
>   compiler and link tools for your target platform. For example, you
>   might have copied the files so you could invoke the compiler or link
>   tool from the command prompt without setting the PATH environment
>   variable accordingly.